# Wait for confirmation dialog return value

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, jquery-events

I have the following jQuery code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() { 

       initConfirmbinding();

       $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
              "Delete": function() { 
                     $(this).dialog("close");            
                     alert("You pressed OK!");
                     return true;
                     }, 
              "Cancel": function() { 
                     $(this).dialog("close"); 
                     return false;
                     } 
        }
      });

    function initConfirmbinding(){
           // Dialog Link 
           $('.confirm').click(function(){
                 return $('#dialog').dialog('open'); // Here it doesn't stops for the return value!!
           });
    }
  </script>
```

And this other code:

```
 ...
<c:foreach ...>
 <h:commandLink styleClass="confirm" action="#{myBean.delete}">
      <img src="/resources/images/delete-bw.png"/>    
 </h:commandLink>
<c/:foreach>

 ...
 <!-- ui-dialog -->
<div id="dialog" title="Question" style="display: none;">
        This item will be deleted, confirm?         
</div>
```

I need to make the call to **myBean.delete** after the user confirms the **dialog**, but it just continues and makes the call with the dialog still open. How can I make the dialog to return a synchronized value? So the commandLink can know whether to execute the action or not.

I know it can use **callbacks**, but callbacks is not an option since the **commandLink** is waiting for the result to decide to execute the action, and if I use callbacks I will need to make a direct call to the commandLink.click which would make an infinite loop.

Even thought, thinking again there could be a way to use **callbacks** but how could I send to the **dialog** which callback to call when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make the execution of code stop and wait. The only thing you can do is to make a modal dialog by blocking out the page under the dialog so the user has to select something before continuing.

Comment: Hello Justing808, yes it's already a `modal dialog, the problem is in the `commandLink` which continues to execute the action right after the **onclick** event take place instead of waiting for the answer of the confirmation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, your problem can be solved if you expose the `#{myBean.delete}` method of bean as a javascript function and call it accordingly in jQueryUI dialog's `Delete` and `Cancel` handlers. 
If you can use the RichFaces library, refer to [`a4j:jsFunction`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Actions.html#sect-Component_Reference-Actions-a4jjsFunction)
But in this case the delete button click has to be pure ajax call. i.e. you can have the dialog invoked in the `onclick` and no action specified.
Otherwise there's no way you can stop the postback from happening.